# How to neglect enum type if the input is empty?

Tags: mysql

I have a query which is like this.

```
SELECT* FROM wallet_transactions 
WHERE `transaction_date` BETWEEN '2020-02-29' AND '2020-10-27' 
AND user_uuid =1 
AND transaction_type = ' ' 
limit 20 offset  0
```

The transaction type column is enum type that is 'CR' or 'DR' The above query works fine if there is a value either it is CR or DR

I need a query which has the enum type is empty and should not care whether the column value is CR or DR  and return result accordingly. how can i achive this?

Comment: Please add your table definition and sample data as text to the question. And did you mean null rather than empty?

Comment: I just wanted this "filter any enum data types  in  single mysql query"why do u need a table defenition for this?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an Enum mapped for ' ' that you are searching for?
Enum values are by default allowed to store NULL (only if they are nullable columns).
If you see empty string in your enum column it may be because you tried adding invalid string to enum column. You can access all those with transaction_type = 0

> If you insert an invalid value into an ENUM (that is, a string not present in the list of permitted values), the empty string is inserted instead as a special error value. This string can be distinguished from a “normal” empty string by the fact that this string has the numeric value 0.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/enum.html

Comment: `SELECT* FROM wallet_transactions WHERE `transaction_date` BETWEEN '2020-02-29' AND '2020-10-27' AND user_uuid =1 AND transaction_type = 'CR' limit 20 offset  0` This is returning two columns but if i use this `SELECT* FROM wallet_transactions WHERE `transaction_date` BETWEEN '2020-02-29' AND '2020-10-27' AND user_uuid =1 AND transaction_type = 'CR' limit 20 offset  0` Returning null i want atleast two columns to be returned with this.

Comment: I dont have an enum mapped for ' ' this which i am looking I want to access all of the enum type but nothing i am getting as a result